# RootView keep reloading when presentViewController is invoke

Tags: ios, objective-c

Have some problem with presentViewConroller. I have a custom view named Calculator, I want to load the view on a button pressed. But every time the Calculator view loaded, the previous view (RootView) will always reload and the view become very messy. Below is the code I used to load the Calculator.

```
-(void)display {
  UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  Calculator *cal = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Calculator"];
  [self presentViewController:cal animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Anyone the reason why the RootView is reload every time I try to load another view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I made some terrible mistakes when subclassing the Calculator class. After I corrected it. Everything is working fine.